# How can I get the current script file name, but without the extension ".php"?

Tags: php, file

If I have PHP script, how can I get the filename of the currently executed file without its extension?

Given the name of a script of the form "jquery.js.php", how can I extract just the "jquery.js" part?

Answer (score 484, accepted):

Just use the [PHP magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) `__FILE__` to get the current filename.

But it seems you want the part without `.php`. So...

```
basename(__FILE__, '.php');
```

A more generic file extension remover would look like this...

```
function chopExtension($filename) {
    return pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
}

var_dump(chopExtension('bob.php')); // string(3) "bob"
var_dump(chopExtension('bob.i.have.dots.zip')); // string(15) "bob.i.have.dots"
```

Using standard string library functions is [much quicker](http://codepad.org/fDO0AvHD), as you'd expect.

```
function chopExtension($filename) {
    return substr($filename, 0, strrpos($filename, '.'));
}
```

Comment: Why not simply use `substr` and `strrchr` to strip off the last `.` and everything behind it?

Comment: @ThiefMaster Because there is something built into PHP to handle file extensions. The wheel exists, and rolls well.

Comment: But a regex might be more expensive!

Comment: @ThieMaster Show me some code for a website where this function is the bottleneck and I'll reconsider.

Comment: @ThieMaster According to [my benchmark](http://codepad.org/eywKhKyY), the `strrpos()` way is much quicker. But the difference is only ~0.388506 over 1000 calls.

Comment: While `__FILE__` gives you the `.php` file that line is in, you actually want `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` for the currently running top-level script (that which was invoked by the web server or directly on the command line)

Comment: @Drew I guess that depends on what you really want.

Comment: agreed with @DrewStephens, `SCRIPT_NAME` or `SCRIPT_FILENAME` would work best

Comment: I agree with @DrewStephens, SCRIPT_NAME or SCRIPT_FILENAME would work best.  I am working inside an include file and __FILE__ fails as it returns the literal file and not the script name in this case

Comment: @alex I agree with you that using standard library functions are much faster.

Although this is my first time seeing this post I caught a mistake in your [codepad](http://codepad.org/fDO0AvHD) that skewed the results shown and I am surprised no one noticed.

On line 14 you named the "now" variable with a "1" but left out the "1" on line 22 when you were subtracting it for the $duration1 result.

Correct [codepad results](http://codepad.org/maktYcbA)

Cheers!

Answer (score 149):

When you want your include to know what file it is in (ie. what script name was actually requested), use:

```
basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], '.php')
```

Because when you are writing to a file you usually know its name.

*Edit: As noted by Alec Teal, if you use symlinks it will show the symlink name instead.*

Comment: That was helpful to me)) needed to get script file name, in **required file**)

Comment: This is wrong, it wont get the actual PHP file, but the file the webserver resolved to the request. Different if you use simlinks.

Comment: Also different if you use PHP-FPM.

Comment: Also if you need the extension too, use `pathinfo($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], PATHINFO_BASENAME);`

Comment: @c00000fd If you need the extension just omit the second parameter...

Answer (score 75):

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

```
pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Answer (score 64):

Here is the difference between `basename(__FILE__, ".php")` and `basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php")`.

`basename(__FILE__, ".php")` shows the name of the file where this code is included - It means that if you include this code in *header.php* and current page is *index.php*, it will return *header* not *index*.

`basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], ".php")` - If you use include this code in *header.php*  and current page is *index.php*, it will return *index* not *header*.

Comment: which is safer `SCRIPT_FILENAME` or `REQUEST_URI`? I know they both are server vars but isn't `REQUEST_URI` a user tampered value? it enables a "URI injection" threat

Comment: both have their own impotence, But you can safe your url using different filers, like mysql_real_escape_string, stripslashes etc..

Comment: @KhandadNiazi `basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], ".php");` will return the folder's name if the link is of the form `http://example.com/somefolder` . While `basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php");` will always return the script's name, in this case `index`.

Answer (score 30):

This might help:

```
basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])
```

it will work even if you are using include.

Comment: That still leaves the `.php` at the end that the OP was trying to get rid of

Comment: @stumpx Then you can do `basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php");`

Comment: I have 2 files, header.php and home.php, the header.php is called in home.php how can i detect in header that the current page is home.php or contact.php so i could change some banner etc.

Answer (score 28):

Here is a list what I've found recently searching an answer:

```
//self name with file extension
echo basename(__FILE__) . '<br>';
//self name without file extension
echo basename(__FILE__, '.php') . '<br>';
//self full url with file extension
echo __FILE__ . '<br>';

//parent file parent folder name
echo basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) . '<br>';
//parent file parent folder name with //s
echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . '<br>';

// parent file name without file extension
echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php") . '<br>';
// parent file name with file extension
echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '<br>';
// parent file relative url with file etension
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '<br>';

// parent file name without file extension
echo basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], '.php') . '<br>';
// parent file name with file extension
echo basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]) . '<br>';
// parent file full url with file extension
echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] . '<br>';

//self name without file extension
echo pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . '<br>';
//self file extension
echo pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) . '<br>';

// parent file name with file extension
echo basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

Don't forget to remove :)

> `<br>`

Comment: So... SCRIPT_NAME, SCRIPT_FILENAME and PHP_SELF are 3 different things, right? (Why so many vars with same value?! Rasmus was on drugs for sure)

Comment: Scenario: `index.php` includes `header.php` which in turn includes `functions.php`, where `log_location()` resides. I call `log_location()` in `header.php`, and then I run `index.php`. All of the above function print out either function or index or domain or some variation of these. I wan't to know which PHP script called the function. Is it even possible (in a one-liner)? @begoyan

Answer (score 22):

alex's answer is correct but you could also do this without regular expressions like so:

```
str_replace(".php", "", basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]));
```

Comment: This runs the risk of mangling a filename like `hey.php-i-am-a-weird-filename.php`.

Comment: I already thought of that but I figured they were using it for the single page mentioned in the question.  You could also check to see if the ".php" is at the end of the string.  Not saying your question is wrong but regular espressions can be kind of a pain in the ass and are usually used in scenarios where a much simpler and less resource intensive method could be used.

Comment: Shofner I ran some benchmarks and your way runs about twice as quick, but still over 1000 iterations the difference is 0.003231 microseconds.

Answer (score 9):

you can also use this:

```
echo $pageName = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

Answer (score 5):

A more general way would be using [pathinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.pathinfo.php). Since Version 5.2 it supports `PATHINFO_FILENAME`.

So

```
pathinfo(__FILE__,PATHINFO_FILENAME)
```

will also do what you need.

Answer (score 5):

**$argv[0]**

I've found it much simpler to use `$argv[0]`.  The name of the executing script is always the first element in the `$argv` array.  Unlike all other methods suggested in other answers, this method does not require the use of `basename()` to remove the directory tree.  For example:

- `echo __FILE__;` returns something like `/my/directory/path/my_script.php`
- `echo $argv[0];` returns `my_script.php`\

---

**Update:**

@Martin points out that the behavior of `$argv[0]` changes when running CLI. The information page about `$argv` on [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) states,

> The first argument $argv[0] is always the name that was used to run the script.

However, a comment from (at the time of this edit) six years ago states,

> Sometimes $argv can be null, such as when "register-argc-argv" is set to false.  In some cases I've found the variable is populated correctly when running "php-cli" instead of just "php" from the command line (or cron).

Please note that based on the grammar of the text, I expect the comment author meant to say the variable is populated *incorrectly* when running "php-cli." I could be putting words in the commenter's mouth, but it seems funny to say that in some cases the function occasionally behaves correctly.

Comment: on CLI argV returns a full path.

Comment: @Martin It appears $argv using CLI does have that problem. According to [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) $argv[0] should return just the script name, but a comment at the bottom of the page suggests (based on correcting its grammar), that the behavior you're seeing has been an issue for years. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: It is yes possible for $argv[ 0 ] to be null.

Answer (score 4):

Example:

included File: `config.php`

```
<?php
  $file_name_one = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], '.php');
  $file_name_two = basename(__FILE__, '.php');
?>
```

executed File: `index.php`

```
<?php
  require('config.php');
  print $file_name_one."<br>\n"; // Result: index
  print $file_name_two."<br>\n"; // Result: config
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This

```
$current_file_name = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
echo $current_file_name;
```

Comment: This works even in CLI mode.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me, even when run inside an included PHP file, and you want the filename of the current php file running:

```
$currentPage= $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
$currentPage = substr($currentPage, 1);
echo $currentPage;
```

Result:

> index.php

Answer (score 3):

Although `__FILE__` and `$_SERVER` are the best approaches but this can be an alternative in some cases:

```
get_included_files();
```

It contains the file path where you are calling it from and all other includes.

Comment: It should be clarified that the first calling script is always `[0]`; so if `fileA.php` includes `fileB.php` which itself calls class `ClassA.php` which uses this function; then all of the files above will have `get_included_files()[0] === 'fileA.php'` . This is a great little function for traversing includes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```html
$file = basename($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);//Filename requested
```

Comment: Wouldn't `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` be a better idea in case the script is being run on a terminal as suggested by @drew-stephens in the comments above

Comment: using basename will canonicalize the filename and prevent path traversal ../../ attack

Comment: My apologies... What I meant was 
`$file = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$filename = "jquery.js.php";
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);//will output: php
$file_basename = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);//will output: jquery.js
```

Answer (score 1):

`__FILE__` use examples based on localhost server results:

```
echo __FILE__;
// C:\LocalServer\www\templates\page.php

echo strrchr( __FILE__ , '\\' );
// \page.php

echo substr( strrchr( __FILE__ , '\\' ), 1);
// page.php

echo basename(__FILE__, '.php');
// page
```

Answer (score 1):

As some said `basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], '.php')` and `basename( __FILE__, '.php')` are good ways to test this.

To me using the second was the solution for some validation instructions I was making