# Get filename of file which ran PHP include

Tags: php, include

When using the PHP `include`, how can I find out which file is calling the `include`? In short, what is the parent's file filename?

Comment: A better question is why do you need to know this? Perhaps there's a better way of explicitly doing what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to know this so that I can use an include to replace the whole head section of the document. In the head section I am dynamically creating the label by str_replacing the filename hyphens with spaces and uc words to cap it. Problem is, the file it is in is the included file not the parent. I am using the answer by @animuson (accepted answer) just in case anyone is still wondering why this might be desired.

Comment: **Wadih M.'s answer is the correct answer**  if albeit a bit messy. Most everything else just blindly goes to the parent *most* file, *not* the intermediary includes. I'd have up-voted the answer though the accepted answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An easy way is to assign a variable in the parent file (before the inclue), then reference that variable in the included file.

**Parent File:**

```
$myvar_not_replicated = __FILE__; // Make sure nothing else is going to overwrite
include 'other_file.php';
```

**Included File:**

```
if (isset($myvar_not_replicated)) echo "{$myvar_not_replicated} included me";
else echo "Unknown file included me";
```

---

You could also mess around with [`get_included_files()`](http://php.net/get_included_files) or [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) and find the event when and where the file got included, but that can get a little messy and complicated.

Comment: this is a workaround, not a answer. It would be nice if the author would remove it. be an example.

Answer (score 17):

```
$fileList = get_included_files();
$topMost = $fileList[0];
if ($topMost == __FILE__) echo 'no parents';
else echo "parent is $topMost";
```

I think this should give the right result when there's a single parent.

By that I mean the situation where the parent is not a required or an included file itself.

Comment: this answer is wrong because get_included_files returns all files a file has included. The OP asked the opposite, he wanted to know witch file included the file.

Answer (score 17):

Late answer, but ...

I check the running parent filename by using:

```
$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] // or 
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] // (with query string)
```

Comment: This should be more highly rated as this gives the correct answer without needing to edit the container files for an include. I have an include that needed the name of its container file and this sure beats changing the `$var` values in 100+ other pages as the other answers suggest.

Comment: **HIGHLY INCORRECT ANSWER** ! `SCRIPT_NAME` returns the most first file. and `REQUEST_URI` is out of question! they wont help in any CMS.  Use `debug_backtrace()` or `get_included_files()`

Comment: @T.Todua these qualifiers are valid but are well out of the scope of this question (and answer). `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` is the value needed here.

Answer (score 12):

You could use debug_backtrace() directly with no additional changes from within the included file:

```
$including_filename = pathinfo(debug_backtrace()[0]['file'])['basename'];
```

This will give you the name of the file that's including you.

To see everything you have access to from within the included file, run this from within it:

```
print_r(debug_backtrace());
```

You will get something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file] => /var/folder/folder/folder/file.php
            [line] => 554
            [function] => include
        )

)
```

Comment: It should be noted that sometimes instead of [0], [1] should be used.

Comment: @piotao Can you elaborate or provide a link for explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Got this from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35622743/9270227

```
echo "Parent full URL: ";
echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 2):

I was searching same information on web for complement my online course about php and found two ways. The first was

```
$file = baseline($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
echo $file;  //that outputs file name
```

**BUT**, in include or require cases it gets the final file that it's included or required.
Also found this, the second

```
$file = __FILE__;
echo $file; //that outputs the absolute way from file
```

**BUT** i just was looking for the file name. 
So... I mix it up and it worths well!

```
$file = basename(__FILE__);
echo $file; //that outputs the file name itself (no include/require problems)
```

Comment: this is not a answer, it is a workaround.

Comment: I 'm looking for your answer and i just can't find it...

Answer (score -2):

In the parent file, add this line before including the child file:

```
$_SESSION['parent_file'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

And then in the child file, read the session variable:

```
$parent_file = $_SESSION['parent_file']
```