# Find targeted #id from parent includer with php

Tags: php, url, url-parameters, require-once

I have this code that I include with a `require_once()`. 
I'm looking to set the link's class to "Active" if the user is on it's page. I've managed to do so if the link is intended for a file but I have no clue on how to proceed for the url `./index.php#About` as this code will also match `./index.php`.
Also, I'd rather not use variables on each page and check them afterwards like explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393145/get-filename-of-file-which-ran-php-include).

```
<a href="./" id="Nav-Title"></a>
<a href="./account.php" <?php if(basename(get_included_files()[0], '.php') == "account") echo 'class="Active"';?>>Mon Compte<span>2</span></a>
<a href="./login.php" <?php if(basename(get_included_files()[0], '.php') == "login") echo 'class="Active"';?>>Se Connecter</a>
<a href="./#About">À Propos</a>
<a href="./discover.php" <?php if(basename(get_included_files()[0], '.php') == "discover") echo 'class="Active"';?>>Découvrir</a>
<a href="./search.php" <?php if(basename(get_included_files()[0], '.php') == "search") echo 'class="Active"';?>>Trouver</a>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Define "easy way". And what do you mean by "trigger"?

Comment: Well, something like `if(basename(get_included_files()[0], '.php') == "index"` but that only matches the url `./index.php#About` or `./#About`

Comment: Isn't that what you want to match?

Comment: I want to match `./index.php#About` but not `./index.php`

Comment: You may want to add that information to your less than clear question. Explain *exactly* what you want to do and what you've tried.

Comment: Done! Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Yes, this solves my issue. Thanks for finding the answer! Sorry for duplicate.