# How to get the page/file name of a parent page loaded with AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, echo

This is a very summarized snippet of what I'd like to do. In this example, I want $page_title to return "page-one" on blogroll.php (and ultimately, return different values because it'll be on different pages). Here's what I have, but $page_title returns "blogroll".

EDIT TO SHOW FULL CODE

```
mysite.com/page-one.php:
 <div class="blogroll"></div>
 <script>
     $(window).scroll(function () { 
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('body').height() / 2) {
       $('.blogroll').load('blogroll.php');
       $(window).unbind('scroll');
     } 
   });
 </script>


mysite.com/blogroll.php:
 <?php
 $page_name = basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], ".php");
  switch ($page_name) {
     case "page-one":
         $categ = 1; break;

     case "page-two":
         $categ = '8'; break;

       ...there are many more cases
 }?>
```

Comment: Can you post your full code please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393145/get-filename-of-file-which-ran-php-include

Comment: @DanielJames added