# Name of current file PHP

Tags: php, web, filenames

How do you get JUST the current files name that is being used? I need the name only (myFile.php NEEDS TO BE myFile)

`$_SERVER` and `__FILE__` constants are NOT the answers I am looking for.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php If you cannot find something that exactly matches your requirements - combine functions. There is obviously no function `run_facebook();`. So in your case - use `__FILE__` and mentioned function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221333/get-the-current-script-file-name'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
basename(__FILE__, '.php');
```

See also here: http://php.net/basename, or, if you like

```
pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

This last one works also if the extension is different from .php without the need to specify it, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: What if a current extension is not `.php`?

Comment: In that case it wouldn't work, but OP mentioned `.php` explicitely, second example works in any case.

Comment: "but OP mentioned .php explicitely" --- then `substr(__FILE__, 0, -4)` would be even cheaper :)

Comment: Yep, I would say that is right, but should be `substr(__FILE__, 0, -4)` or you'd leave the final dot.

Comment: Yep, it's hard to count to 4 in the morning )

Answer (score 0):

Try strstr :

```
<?php
$file  = 'myFile.php';
$name = strstr($file, '.');
echo $name; // prints .php

$file  = 'myFile.php';
$name = strstr($file, '.' ,true);
echo $name; // prints myFile
?>
```

You can find more examples on how to use this at
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

This should work for you.