# How to get the current page name(url) and add it as a class to the "body"

Tags: php, html

I am trying to figure out a way through php to:

1) Get the name of the current page  through it's url http://website.com/videos/**a-great-video**

2) Add it as a class to the body

```
<body class="a-great-video"></body>
```

3) I'm trying to create a PHP variable for the current page name but not sure how to grab it with PHP. The class will be added through PHP or at least that's the goal. If you have another way of doing this, please feel free.

Setup Information:

The server runs Apache 2.0 and uses mod_rewrite.

```
Example URL: http://localhost:8888/romwod/members/signup
```

What I'm trying to get: "**signup**" or "**members-signup**"

Comment: How does your code pull in the body tag? Are you using a templating engine?  If I understand correctly you want: `<body class="a-great-video">`?

Comment: Yes that's correct. It uses a template engine. Basically header and footer php includes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the current script file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221333/get-the-current-script-file-name)

Comment: In a way yes but I'm trying to get the file name after the mod_rewrite.

Comment: can you pass info to a router instead of using rewrite for the site? how is the script or content unaware of the real path name? can you modify your dom depending on the view loaded?

Comment: does `window.location.pathname` work for you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<?php
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    preg_match('|.*/(.*)|', $url, $matches);
?>
<body class = "<?php echo $matches[1]; ?>">
```

Comment: I was not the person whom gave you the down, but $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) returns the full path, not just the fine name

Comment: Here is what it returned: /site/members/index and here is the original url http://localhost:8888/site/members/signup

Is there anyway to get the rewritten page url? It uses mod_rewrite. Also is there any way to remove the trailing folder structure and only get the word "signup" as the output or even "members/signup". I can then just do a preg_replace to switch the "/" with "-" for the class names.

Comment: It worked! You just have $url wrapped in quotes so it's reading it as a string. As soon as I remove the quotes it works like magic.  
If you can edit I'll mark it as the correct answer

Comment: @ValeryStatichny if the page name at one point is "/thanks?id=HWZNK-4eaef238eccb81d6" how can I cut out everything after the "?" including the "?"

Comment: Solved. if anyone needs this, it replaces everything after the question mark: 

$pagename_clean = substr($matches[1], 0, strpos( $matches[1], '?'));

Comment: @user3768940, the task was to work with pages after mod_rewrite module.

Comment: You can modernize your regexp to |.*/(.*)\?.*| in such case.

Answer (score 0):

To get your current page name use:

```
basename(__FILE__);
```

To include it in your body as a class:

```
<body class="<?php basename(__FILE__);?>">
```

Comment: I've added this in but since my site works with included files, if I add that code to the header.php file in my site, it returns header.php and not the page name. My site uses mod_rewrite so I'm trying to get the url name of the last piece of url. Basically the terms after the last "/" in the url.