# php get the php name from the url

Tags: php, php-5.4

I have these types of urls

```
something1/anotherThing1/View/fileName.php

something2/anotherThing2/View/fileName2.php?variable1=value1&variable2=value2

...
```

I want to get the `fileName` without the `.php`

#### I tried this

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

but it seems it gives me the whole url.

Maybe I need a regualr expression.

Could you help me please. i am not good in PHP and i just need this small issue.

appreciate it

Comment: Do you want to be able to run the file without the extension or do  you want to get the name of the file inside the script, getting rid of the extension? clear that out

Comment: Maybe `__FILE__`? If you're inside the actual file and not in an included one

Comment: @JuanRocamonde i need the name of the file inside a script, that file name is in the url and i want to get it inside a script. is that clear please?

Comment: you can get rid of the .php extension by using `trim($var, ".php")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 echo basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]); //with php
    echo '<br>';
    echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");//without php
```

check this answer

[Get the current script file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221333/get-the-current-script-file-name)

Comment: yes it works, plus one, i will accept your answer when the system allows. many thanks

Comment: mine pleasure dear :)