# MySQL - How to use file name as a part of Query?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm very new to the MySQL world so I'm sorry if this might be something obvious!

What I'm trying to do is a Query that outputs price data on different pages, at the moment it works fine - however on each page i use the query I have to change the productpage name in the query. How can I automatically get the filename of the page (excluding .PHP) and insert that name into the query? (I have a corresponding column in the DB with all the different page names)

```
$query=("SELECT * 
        FROM database e 
        JOIN validdate1 r ON e.datevalid1=r.id 
        JOIN validdate2 d ON e.datevalid2=d.id 
        WHERE productpage='page01' 
        ORDER BY price2,
```

So rather than manually entering page01, i want it to be fetched from the file name (in this case is page01.php).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have a look at the options: `print_r($_SERVER);`

Comment: if the only thing that changes is the file  name, you only need one page and then use mod rewrite to send all traffic to it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the current script file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221333/get-the-current-script-file-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the php page name using below code

```
$page=basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); /* Returns PHP File Name */
$page_name=str_replace(".php","",$page);

$query=("SELECT * 
    FROM database e 
    JOIN validdate1 r ON e.datevalid1=r.id 
    JOIN validdate2 d ON e.datevalid2=d.id 
    WHERE productpage='$page_name' 
    ORDER BY price2,
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you very much Sameeraa4ever (and everyone else that replied for that matter!)

Answer (score 1):

`echo __FILE__;` outputs the current filename.

`echo preg_replace('/\.php$/', '', __FILE__);` outputs the current filename without '.php'.

[Get the current script file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221333/get-the-current-script-file-name)

Answer (score 1):

Use variable interpolation in your query:

```
$pageName = basename(__FILE__, '.php');
$query=("SELECT * FROM database e JOIN validdate1 r ON e.datevalid1=r.id JOIN validdate2 d ON e.datevalid2=d.id WHERE productpage='$pageName' ORDER BY price2");
```

...or use a prepared statement and submit the page name as an argument

Answer (score 0):

If the page link is some thing like this:
http://yourhost/abc/page1

You can get /abc/page1 by using this:

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)
```

Depends on the structure of your URL, you can use explode to get page 1