# How can I place the name of the file inbetween the title tags in html?

Tags: php, dom

What I would like to is have a php with a template function in it e.g.

Template.php

```
function htmlTemplate($title){
echo'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>'.$title.'</title>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>';
}
```

what I would like to do is have a file that assigns $title  with the name of itself calls the function htmlTemplate($title)

What I would like to do is have multiple documents call this function and update the title accordingly:

example.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>example</title>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I can then rename the file if needed and have the title change as well as add other content using DOM and other php function calls

Comment: And what exactly is the question?

Comment: The qustion is how can i place the name of the file inbetween the title tags in html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want use php your function is:

```
function htmlTemplate(){
echo'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>'. basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '.php') .'</title>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>';
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, I would however change it to `basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '.php')` to drop `.php` extension as in question author's example.

Comment: Oh I forget remove file extension. Thanks @Przemek

Comment: and you have also forgot to edit your answer ;). I think it needs to be updated to better suit OP.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
<h1><?php echo str_replace( array('/', '.php'), $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?></h1>
```

Comment: Similar i wan't avoid having the extension in the title

Comment: Works a charm, however the other answer was easier to handle so that gets the accepted answer, though I will still give this +1 ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `basename` function with the `__FILE__` constant, something like this:

```
$title = basename(__FILE__, '.php');
```

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221333/get-the-current-script-file-name) for more info and here's some links:

[`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)
[`__FILE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

**EDIT**

Here's an idea of how to use it:

```
include('Template.php');
$currTitle = basename(__FILE__, '.php');
htmlTemplate($currTitle);
```

Something like that.