# Get file name if it's not part of url

Tags: php

url:

```
localhost/story/
```

current file is index.php
Is there a way to get file name (index.php) in php, if it's not part of url.

`basename(__FILE__)` doesn't work because result is `contact.php` probably because `contact.php` is included at the beginning of `index.php`.

Comment: Tweak the Web server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the current script file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221333/get-the-current-script-file-name)

Comment: You can look into `$_SERVER` or use the `__FILE__` constant, if I understand Your question correctly.

Comment: like mentioned on the duplicate, use `__FILE__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Answer (score 2):

`__FILE__` will get current filename

```
echo basename(__FILE__);
```

> The [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function returns the filename from a path.

Comment: @bonaca did you test it? I don't think what you claim is true

Comment: Tested. In this case result is `contact.php` probably because `contact.php` is included at the beginning of `index.php`.

Answer (score -1):

@madankundu answer is ok, but you shouldn't access request variables directly. Better is:

```
echo basename(filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'PHP_SELF'));
```