# PHP: How to get file name that is included in main file?

Tags: php

I have a PHP file called ***particular.php***. I have included ***family.php*** inside ***particular.php*** with include function.

So when I do ***$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]*** I get particular.php. I want to get file name family.php.

I have several files that needs to redirect to included file automatically. For that I need to get included files name rather than main file name.

Comment: $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] tells only about current PHP file getting executed no matter what you are including in it.

Comment: Why you want `family.php`? What is your next action if you get family.php...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the current script file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221333/get-the-current-script-file-name)

Comment: Don't use `PHP_SELF`, use `__FILE__` to get the current processed file from within a php file. This and similar Question where already answered several times. Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4221345/3828957) for example.

Answer (score 1):

There is a PHP function called ***get_included_files()***. This stores all the included files.