PHP check if the page file name if index.php echo or else nothing
I want to set a button on the header of the page but this button will never be displayed on the index.php page but on all other pages. It is a GO BACK button so obviously it cannot be seen on index.php.
Here is what I have
`<?php
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'index.php')){
 echo '';
}
else{
 echo 'show a button here';
}
?>`

The problem is that no matter what page I am it always display the button. All pages have different names like index.php contact.php news.php etc
EDIT: the url is example.com/beta/index.php
echo request_uri says:
/4/
Edit 2: In my .htaccess I hide the .php extensions so the pages does not display like /index.php but just /index
Edit 3: It is now working if I go to example.com/beta/index.php but not if I go to example.com/beta/ because its empty so the button is displayed anyway.
I am using the following test code:
<?php

if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/index.php')){
 echo '';
}
elseif (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'index')){
 echo '';
}
elseif (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '')){
 echo '';
}
elseif (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/4/')){
 echo '';
}
else{
 echo 'show a button here';
}
?>


Hard to really tell what's going on but maybe this yields different results for you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4221333/4616087

a) Why do you need a "back" button in your page? Every browser provides one already

b) What debugging have you done? Test the value of $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. Test the output of stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'index.php'), and see what you get, to narrow down the issue. We can't see your URLs, so we can't test it for you

the url is example.com/beta/index.php

How is javascript related?

the url is example.com/beta/index.php...with that value your code works as expected - demo: https://3v4l.org/ch4cF . Like I said, do some basic debugging and see what's really happening in that scenario when you run it in your page

request uri says:
/4/

Evidently then, index.php doesn't feature in the URL being requested. Surely you could see that fact already in your browser? Presumably your site uses some kind of routing engine to process URLs, rather than relying directly on filenames?

Can it be that in -htaccess I hide the .php extensions ?

Maybe? How should we know? It's your site - presumably you should know that already?!

the pages does not display like /index.php but just /index...so surely you can just test for index your stripos() call, rather than index.php? (I'd have hoped that was already self-evident??)

OK it almost worked. It works if I go to example.com/index but because index is the main page, if I go to example.com it does not work... You need to set /index

Well of course...you're only doing a simple string match - it's not magic

You should consider making a special case in your code for that situation

I am just a noob. How do I do a special case ?

Just add another condition to the if. I assume in the the case of the URL being only example.com that the REQUEST_URI returns nothing? If so, then if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'index.php' || stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '')))

(stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'index' || stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ''))) did not worked

Well I did say it referred to a particular case. Did you test that my assumption was correct? Maybe REQUEST_URI returns / instead in that scenario? If so, then test for that. All you have to do is look at what the REQUEST_URI actually contains, and then write the code to test for the one you want to match!

P.S. Here's tip, since you are a beginner: When talking to people about your programming problems, never just say "did not work"...that tells us nothing about what happened. We cannot use that to tell you what's wrong. Always provide debugging info - whether that's an error message, or an unexpected output, and provide sample data which went into it when you tested. Then we know what really happened. Knowing what did happen is far more useful than knowing what didn't happen, when trying to diagnose a fault. This is true for your own diagnosis efforts too, not just explaining to others!

ok ADyson, thanks for the tip. Could you please write an answer so I can select it as the correct answer for future users having the same problem please

Well, what was correct in the end? Did you have to test for /? Then I can write the correct thing in the answer

I am trying the following <?php
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/index.php')){
echo '';
}
elseif (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'index')){
echo '';
}
elseif (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '')){
echo '';
}
elseif (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')){
echo '';
}
else{
echo 'show a button here';
}
?> but it still does not work when going to example.com/beta/ without adding /index

So /beta is your test site, I guess? If so, then you'll need to add condition for that too! Same concept as before - add a condition for all URI strings you need to test for.

I see you've added conditions for both '' and/. Don't do that unless they both can occur, and both meet your criteria. Test for which one actually occurs (as I said) and then test for that only. Otherwise it's a waste of CPU, and also just makes your code harder to read. And when you come back to it in 6 months to make changes, you might be scratching your head about why you added an extra condition, which then makes your code harder to maintain!

Yes /beta/ is the folder I am using before I move to the root (main) folder

Couldn't you "just" set a variable and check if it's set/empty/not set instead of the filename/url checks?

@brombeer how to do it?

This is just a case of doing some simple string matching.
First you should make a list of all the URIs where the button should not be displayed.
To work out what they are, add something like print_r($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); to the top of your script. Then visit each of the pages / URLs where you don't want the button to appear, and copy the result of that print_r statement (or at least the part of it which identifies a specific page, rather than for example, querystring data).
Once you have your list, you can start writing the code. You simply want to check whether the actual Request URI contains any of the strings (representing the page) from your testing.
If you have several values to test for, you could write a long if statement like this:
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'index') !== false || stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '') !== false || stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/4/') !== false){
 echo '';
}
else{
 echo 'show a button here';
}

Or a long series of if statements:
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'index') !== false){
 echo '';
}
elseif (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '') !== false){
 echo '';
}
elseif (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/4/') !== false){
 echo '';
}
else{
 echo 'show a button here';
}

But this gets cumbersome and tedious (and hard to read) pretty quickly. The neater way to do it would be to put all the values into an array and test if the URI contains any of the values in the array:
$pages = ['', 'index', '/4/'];
$buttonText = "<button>Button</button>";

foreach ($pages as $page) {
  if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $page) !== false) {
    $buttonText = '';
  }
}

echo $buttonText;

Note that all this relies on partial matches of the REQUEST_URI. So if you have a real URI like /test/4/ which contains your "test" page but also contains /4/ (perhaps as a reference to an data item with ID 4, for example) then the code above will match it and hide the button. You may want to consider a more sophisticated strategy at some point, if you encounter this sort of issue.

N.B. I would also suggest that having a "back" button in your site is probably redundant - the same feature is available as standard in every web browser already.

it works on all pages but keep displaying the button on example.com/4/ if I go to example.com/4/index it works perfect

but keep displaying the button on example.com/4/...evidently the condition doesn't match then. Do what I said in the answer and test the REQUEST_URI again for the example.com/4/ page, and see what value it produces. Then adjust your code accordingly. The values in my answer are simply examples - as I said before, I can't see what your REQUEST_URI values really contain, but you can easily test it.
